# Using Keras mobilenet pretrained implementation issue

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to use mobilenetv2 for some learning purpose and trying to do some modification in architecture. No matter what I change in the model structure for instance if I remove two inverted blocks in the below code which I have commented, I still get the same number of layers for instance 156 layers. I was assuming removing some layers from the below code will provide less no of layers. Thanks, help is highly appreciated.

```
    BASE_WEIGHT_PATH = ('https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/'
    'keras-applications/mobilenet_v2/')
    layers = None
    def MobileNetV2(input_shape=None,alpha=1.0,include_top=True,weights='imagenet',
    input_tensor=None,pooling=None,classes=1000,classifier_activation='softmax',**kwargs):
    global layers
    if input_shape is None and input_tensor is not None:
      try:
        backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor)
      except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('input_tensor: ', input_tensor, 'is type: ',
                       type(input_tensor), 'which is not a valid type')

     if input_shape is None and not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
       default_size = 224
     elif input_shape is None and backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
       if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        rows = backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[2]
        cols = backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[3]
       else:
        rows = backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[1]
        cols = backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[2]

       if rows == cols and rows in [96, 128, 160, 192, 224]:
        default_size = rows
       else:
        default_size = 224
    elif input_shape is None:
     default_size = 224
    else:
     if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
       rows = input_shape[1]
       cols = input_shape[2]
     else:
       rows = input_shape[0]
       cols = input_shape[1]
     if rows == cols and rows in [96, 128, 160, 192, 224]:
       default_size = rows
     else:
       default_size = 224
    input_shape = imagenet_utils.obtain_input_shape(input_shape,
      default_size=default_size,
      min_size=32,
      data_format=backend.image_data_format(),
      require_flatten=include_top,
      weights=weights)

    if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
      row_axis, col_axis = (0, 1)
    else:
     row_axis, col_axis = (1, 2)
   rows = input_shape[row_axis]
   cols = input_shape[col_axis]
   if input_tensor is None:
    img_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
   else:
    if not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
      img_input = layers.Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
    else:
      img_input = input_tensor

  channel_axis = 1 if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1

  first_block_filters = _make_divisible(32 * alpha, 8)
  x = layers.Conv2D(first_block_filters,kernel_size=3,strides=(2, 2),padding='same',use_bias=False,name='Conv1')(img_input)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.999, name='bn_Conv1')(x)
  x = layers.ReLU(6., name='Conv1_relu')(x)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=16, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=1, block_id=0)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=24, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=1)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=24, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=2)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=32, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=3)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=32, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=4)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=32, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=5)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=64, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=6)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=64, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=7)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=64, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=8)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=64, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=9)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=96, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=10)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=96, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=11)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=96, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=12)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=160, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=13)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=160, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=14)
  #########################################################################################
  #x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=160, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=15)
  #########################################################################################
  #x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=320, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=16)
  if alpha > 1.0:
    last_block_filters = _make_divisible(1280 * alpha, 8)
  else:
    last_block_filters = 1280
  x = layers.Conv2D(last_block_filters, kernel_size=1, use_bias=False, name='Conv_1')(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.999, name='Conv_1_bn')(x)
  x = layers.ReLU(6., name='out_relu')(x)
  if include_top:
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    imagenet_utils.validate_activation(classifier_activation, weights)
    x = layers.Dense(classes, activation=classifier_activation,name='predictions')(x)
  else:
    if pooling == 'avg':
      x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    elif pooling == 'max':
      x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
  if input_tensor is not None:
    inputs = layer_utils.get_source_inputs(input_tensor)
  else:
    inputs = img_input
  # Create model.
  model = training.Model(inputs, x, name='mobilenetv2_%0.2f_%s' % (alpha, rows))
  # Load weights.
  if weights == 'imagenet':
    if include_top:
      model_name = ('mobilenet_v2_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_' +str(alpha) + '_' + str(rows) + '.h5')
      weight_path = BASE_WEIGHT_PATH + model_name
      weights_path = data_utils.get_file(
          model_name, weight_path, cache_subdir='models')  
    model.load_weights(weights_path)    
  elif weights is not None:
    model.load_weights(weights)
    layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers])
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer_name = layer.name
        layer.set_weights(layer_dict[layer_name].get_weights())
  return model

def _inverted_res_block(inputs, expansion, stride, alpha, filters, block_id):
  """Inverted ResNet block."""
  channel_axis = 1 if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1
  in_channels = backend.int_shape(inputs)[channel_axis]
  pointwise_conv_filters = int(filters * alpha)
  pointwise_filters = _make_divisible(pointwise_conv_filters, 8)
  x = inputs
  prefix = 'block_{}_'.format(block_id)
  if block_id:
    # Expand
    x = layers.Conv2D(expansion * in_channels,kernel_size=1,padding='same',use_bias=False,activation=None,name=prefix + 'expand')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis,epsilon=1e-3,momentum=0.999,name=prefix + 'expand_BN')(x)
    x = layers.ReLU(6., name=prefix + 'expand_relu')(x)
  else:
    prefix = 'expanded_conv_'
  # Depthwise
  if stride == 2:
    x = layers.ZeroPadding2D(
        padding=imagenet_utils.correct_pad(x, 3),
        name=prefix + 'pad')(x)
  x = layers.DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size=3,strides=stride,activation=None,use_bias=False,padding='same' if stride == 1 else 'valid',
      name=prefix + 'depthwise')(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis,epsilon=1e-3,momentum=0.999,name=prefix + 'depthwise_BN')(x)
  x = layers.ReLU(6., name=prefix + 'depthwise_relu')(x)
  x = layers.Conv2D(pointwise_filters,kernel_size=1,padding='same',use_bias=False,activation=None,name=prefix + 'project')(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis,epsilon=1e-3,momentum=0.999,name=prefix + 'project_BN')(x)
  if in_channels == pointwise_filters and stride == 1:
    return layers.Add(name=prefix + 'add')([inputs, x])
  return x

def _make_divisible(v, divisor, min_value=None):
  if min_value is None:
    min_value = divisor
  new_v = max(min_value, int(v + divisor / 2) // divisor * divisor)
  # Make sure that round down does not go down by more than 10%.
  if new_v < 0.9 * v:
    new_v += divisor
  return new_v
model=tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=None, alpha=1.0, include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
```

Comment: Can you remove irrelevant parts? Because there are too much code to inspect. It would be better to include only where you remove layers and get the 156 layers instance.

Comment: You have all of this code, and in the end you use tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2, which does not use any code modifications you made. Are you somehow expecting that it will use your code implementation?

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy  thanks I have sorted out the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Frightera, I have sorted out issue